# China transit visa: Fly from DPS (Indonesia) to Shanghai with a layover (2hrs) in Beijing

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, china, shanghai, beijing

I fly from DPS to Shanghai with a 2-hour layover in Beijing.  Do I have to pass through immigration in Beijing or can I do it in Shanghai where I would like to stay for 5 days with a transit visa?

I just don't want any problems when I land in Beijing.  I will not leave the airport during my 2-hour stay.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/132433/im-from-guatemala-do-i-need-a-transit-visa-if-my-flight-has-two-stops-in-china